# How do I get the value of a variable whose name is based on another variable?

Tags: terraform

inside variables.tf

```
locals {
  env_name = lower(terraform.workspace)
}
```

inside tfvars

```
hc-auth-demo-port= 8003
```

main.tf

```
port= ${var.hc-auth-"${local.env_name}"-port}"
```

Getting error:

> This character is not used within the language.

Based on an earlier answer, I've tried (which fixes that error, but doesn't solve my actual problem):

```
port = "${var.hc-auth}-${local.env_name}-port"
```

It is saying hc.auth is not declared:

> An input variable with the name "hc-auth" has not been declared. This variable can be declared with a variable "hc-auth" {} block.

I've declared **hc-auth-default-port** in the variables, so how do I append all the 3 words to build that variable name and get its value?

this is the error msg  --> this means it is looking for a variable hc.auth but in my case I wanted hc-auth-default-port interpolation

How do I get the value of a variable whose name is based on another variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Terraform does not support building variable names from variables, but there is a workaround: using maps.

Provide a map of ports in terraform.tfvars (notice the use of snake_case, not skewer-case, as snake_case is the preferred code style for Terraform code):

```
hc_auth_ports = {
  demo = 8003
}
```

Declare a **map(int)** variable **hc_auth_ports** in main.tf or variables.tf:

```
variable "hc_auth_ports" {
  type = map(int)
}
```

Update main.tf to look up the port for the environment in the **hc_auth_ports**:

```
port = var.hc_auth_ports[local.env_name]
```

Now, you should get the outcome you want:

1. declare the ports for each environment in tfvars
2. able to choose the port for the current environment in main.tf

## Original Answer to original question

The original question was effectively:

> Why do I get error "This character is not used within the language." when trying to append variables in a string?

Here is the port assignment with the errors corrected:

```
port = "${var.hc-auth}-${local.env_name}-port"
```

This kind of expression is called a [String Template](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#string-templates).

Here is the original (broken) expression:

```
port = ${var.hc-auth-"${local.env_name}"-port}"
```

Here is why it doesn't work:

1. missing double quote (`"`) to start the string before `${var.hc_auth` (likely what triggered the error message since `${` is illegal outside a String Template)
2. missing closing brace (`}`) to close the variable interpolation of **var.hc_auth**
3. incorrect double quote (`"`) before `${local.env_name}`
4. incorrect closing brace (`}`) after `-port`

An interpolation takes the following form:

```
${hcl_expression}
```

It must be inside a string.

> A ${ ... } sequence is an interpolation, which evaluates the expression given between the markers, converts the result to a string if necessary, and then inserts it into the final string:
>
> ```
> "Hello, ${var.name}!"
> ```
>
> In the above example, the named object var.name is accessed and its value inserted into the string, producing a result like "Hello, Juan!".

From [Interpolation - String Templates - Configuration Syntax](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#interpolation)

Comment: port = "${var.hc-auth}-${local.env_name}-port"  when giving this it is saying hc.auth is not declared ? see hc-auth-default-port is a complete string assigned in the variables, so how to append them all the 3 words ?

Comment: this is the error msg " An input variable with the name "hc-auth" has not been declared. This variable
can be declared with a variable "hc-auth" {} block."  --> this means it is looking for a variable hc.auth but in my case I wanted hc-auth-default-port interpolation

Comment: still not getting!  tried like this but got as a string not the value >``` "$${{var.hc-auth-${local.env_name}-path}}" ```
 ``` ${{var.hc-auth-default-path}}```

Comment: You can't build variable names this way. I've updated your question to reflect  our troubleshooting and will attempt an answer to it.

Comment: so you are saying like we can't  ?

Comment: Yes, but there's a workaround. I'm revising my answer to provide it.

Comment: Thanks Alain! you saved around 45 lines of code to a single line! You are a hero !

Comment: I'm so glad it worked for you. We've been doing a ton of this with our Terraform and ran into the same issue so this was very familiar.